# Render to targets. Some have MSAA, some don't

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I have 6 textures.
Some were initialized via :-

```
void glTexImage2DMultisample(   GLenum target,
    GLsizei samples,
    GLenum internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLboolean fixedsamplelocations);
```

Some (e.g. for stroke / defer shading / special effect) were initialized via :-

```
glTexImage2D( ... );
```

**(Main question)** Is it possible to render to all of them at once? i.e. How to mix MSAA types of render target?

I have tried that, but I got error `36182`.
From [Multi-sampling Frame Render Objects and Depth Buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654723/multi-sampling-frame-render-objects-and-depth-buffers) .       The error means :-

> GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE is also returned if the value of
> GL_TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS is not the same for all attached
> textures; or, if the attached images are a mix of renderbuffers and
> textures, the value of GL_TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS is not
> GL_TRUE for all attached textures.

Perhaps, such operation is not allowed? I have searched for some explanation :-

1. From https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2DMultisample.xhtml :-

> **fixedsamplelocations**  = Specifies whether the image will use identical sample locations and the same number of samples for all
> texels in the image, and the sample locations will not depend on the
> internal format or size of the image. ,

2. https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Anti-Aliasing says that :-

> If the last argument (fixedsamplelocations) is set to GL_TRUE, the image will use identical
> sample locations and the same number of subsamples for each texel.

^ Nevertheless, there are a few of technical words that I don't know.

- What is a `sample location`?  Does the `sample locations` mean `glLocation` in glsl shader?
  I guess it is the same as `GLsizei samples`, e.g. mostly 1 or 4.  If it is 4, 1 pixel =4 samples.
- Does the `internal format` means somethings like `GL_[components​][size​][type​]`?
- Why `the sample locations` is related to `internal format`?
- Thus I don't understand what `fixedsamplelocations` actually means.
  Many examples use GL_TRUE.  When should it be GL_FALSE?

Comment: You're totally on the wrong track here with the sample locations. The error description you quoted begins with "`GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE `is **also** returned if [...]" This "also" here strongly implies that there are other cases were this error is returned, too. And one of these "other" cases is actually the main case: this error is generated if that not all attachments have the same sample count. You can't mix multisample- and non-multisampled buffers in the same draw call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single FBO, images are either all multisampled or all not multisampled. To do otherwise (even if the MS images have a sample count of 1) will lead to a [framebuffer completeness error](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Completeness_Rules). Not only must all images either be multisampled or non-multisampled, all images must also have the same sample count (the sample count of non-multisampled images is 0).

So what you want is not permitted.

---

The stuff on fixed-sample locations is a completely separate question.

Multisample images of a particular sample count have the same number of samples in each pixel. However, when rendering for anti-aliasing purposes, it is a good idea to vary *where* those samples are in terms of the pixel's area of the screen. This improves the quality of the anti-alising produced by multisampling, as it minimizes any coherency between adjacent sample patterns.

If you turn on fixed sample locations, you're forcing the implementation to *not do this*. So you will get reduced anti-aliasing quality. You would only need to turn this on if you have some shader computation that relies on a consistent location for the samples. This would typically be because you're doing the multisample resolve manually (rather than with a blit).

Comment: Thank a lot of detail explanation.

Comment: To do stroke post-processing that requires non anti-aliased position texture, do I need another draw call?   ( ╥ω╥ )